# Regex to change quoting style

Tags: javascript, regex

In the text that I get, I want to replace all the dialogue quotes with double quotes, while keeping the single quotes used in contractions like "aren’t". I want to use a `String.replace()` with a regular expression to do this..

E:g:

```
var text = "'I'm the cook,' he said, 'it's my job.'";
console.log(text.replace(/*regEx*/, "\""));
//should return → "I'm the cook," he said, "it's my job."
```

Now I know a regex that works for me, at least for the example text.

```
console.log(text.replace(/\B'/g, "\""));
```

However, I wonder if there is any other regex I can use to accomplish this. Just curious.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the best way to do it...

Comment: @MacPrawn Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this can be done reliably. Human language is too complicated. A `'` at the end of a word after an `s` may or may not be a quotation mark.

Comment: How about the text `"This is Tess' pencil."` ?

Comment: The regex I used works for your text, @John Doe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that the regular expression you provided doesn't replace single quotes in the beginning of the string. I came up with this one instead:

```
var str = "'Hello', - she said\n'Hi!' - he whispered\n";
console.log(str.replace(/\B'|'\B/g, "\""));
```